# Can not implement JSTL with new classpath

Tags: java, jstl, facelets, jsp-tags, taglib

I have a big problem to implement my jsp pages.

I'm using Spring 4 with theoretically JSTL 1.2 + Servlet 3.0 in STS (Eclipse Luna) - Tomcat 7. [I saw the article posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info), however I could not solve.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

This url is recognized by the STS IDE (Eclipse). However when I try to open the page displays the error:

> /views/root/index.jsp(1,63) PWC6188: The absolute uri:
>   http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml
>   or the jar files deployed with this application

src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<flow xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow/spring-webflow-2.0.xsd">

    <view-state id="start">
    </view-state>

</flow>
```

src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib

- javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-1.2.1.jar
- javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api-1.2.1.jar

---

Trying with another approach:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

This url is not recognized by the Eclipse IDE. Accusing error in project.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">
```

As some libs who put in pom.xml (maven) the url in that line is recognized, however nothing happens in the browser.

**PS:** Spring in all four projects say they no longer need the file "web.xml" and try to put some tutorials to follow, again accuses the eclipse error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 35 hours of work, I discovered that the error is conflict with more than one library "Servlet" e "JSTL".

Printscreen: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZ3Cu.png